# Как проверить скрипт JS?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!

У меня на некоторых страницах подключен плагин скролла nicescroll.min.js и подключен файл js с инициализацией плагина

```
function initScroll() {
    $(".sidebar-fixed .sidebar-content").niceScroll({
        mousescrollstep: 100,
        cursorcolor: '#ccc',
        cursorborder: '',
        cursorwidth: 3,
        hidecursordelay: 100,
        autohidemode: 'scroll',
        horizrailenabled: false,
        preservenativescrolling: false,
        railpadding: {
            right: 0.5,
            top: 1.5,
            bottom: 1.5
        }
    });
}

function removeScroll() {
    $(".sidebar-fixed .sidebar-content").getNiceScroll().remove();
    $(".sidebar-fixed .sidebar-content").removeAttr('style').removeAttr('tabindex');
}

initScroll();

$(window).on('resize', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if($(window).width() <= 768) {
            removeScroll();
        }
        else {
            initScroll();
        }
    }, 100);
}).resize();
```

Но если к странице плагин не подключен, этот скрипт выдает ошибку из за того что плагин не подключен.

Как в скрипте проверить подключен ли плагин?

прошу помощи в реализации!

Comment: `if($(".sidebar-fixed .sidebar-content").niceScroll)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете проверить пространство имён в `JQuery` и, если плагин подключён, имя плагина должна быть в этом пространстве։

```
if(jQuery().niceScroll) {
     initScroll();
 }
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ.